# Wrong type overloading ++ operator

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading

I try to build a doubly concatenated list in c++ in combination with templates.

If I try to compile the Programm, Visual Studio throws me a

> C2676 Error:Binary Operator "++": Interator" does not define or
>   does not convert this Operator to a useable type

Why does this not work? If I add another method to do the same operation like my overloaded incrementer it works fine, but if I overload the incrementer it throws me that error.

Here some Code:

My NodeElement Class:

```
template<typename T>
class Nodeelement
{
public:
    Nodeelement(T data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        pNext = NULL;
    }
    Nodeelement *pPrev;
    Nodeelement *pNext;
    T data;
};
```

Then my Iterator class:

```
template<typename T>
class Iterator
{
public:
    Nodeelement<T> *itr;
    Iterator(void) : itr(NULL) {}
    Iterator(Nodeelement<T>* le) : itr(le) {}

    void operator=(Nodeelement<T>* le)
    {
        itr = le;
    }

    bool operator!=(Nodeelement<T>* le)
    {
        if (NULL != itr && itr != le)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        if (itr != NULL)
            itr = itr->pNext;
    }

    void operator--()
    {
        if (itr != NULL)
            itr = itr->pPrev;
    }

    T& getData(void)
    {
        return itr->data;
    }
};
```

and then my Node class:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    Nodeelement<T>* pFirst;
    Nodeelement<T>* pLast;
public:
    Node<T>::Node(void) { pFirst = pLast = NULL;}
    Node<T>::~Node() { removeEntry(); }
    void Node<T>::addEntry(T data)
    {
        Nodeelement<T> *newNodeElement = new Nodeelement<T>(data);
        if (isEmpty())
            pLast = pFirst = newNodeElement;
        else
        {
            pLast->pNext = newNodeElement;
            newNodeElement->pPrev = pLast;
            pLast = newNodeElement;
        }
    }
    bool isEmpty(void) { return (pFirst == NULL) ? true : false; }
    void removeEntry(void)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            return;

        while (pFirst->pNext != NULL)
        {
            Nodeelement<T> *pNow = pLast->pPrev;
            pNow->pNext = NULL;
            delete pLast;
            pLast = pNow;
        }
        delete pFirst;
        pFirst = NULL;
    };
    void removeEntry(Iterator<T>& it)
    {
        if (pFirst->pNext == NULL)
        {
            delete pFirst;
            pFirst = pNext = NULL;
        }
        else if (it == pFirst)
        {
            pFirst = pFirst->pNext;
            delete pFirst->pPrev;
            pFirst->pPrev = NULL;
        }
        else if (it == pLast)
        {
            pLast = pLast->pPrev;

            delete pLast->pNext;
            pLast->pNext = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            it.itr->pPrev->pNext = it.itr->pNext;
            it.iter->pNext->pPrev = it.iter->pPrev;
            delete it.itr;
        }
    };

    Nodeelement<T>* start(void) { return pFirst; }
    Nodeelement<T>* postpLast(void)
    {
        if (pLast == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else
            return pLast->pNext;
    }
};
```

And the main.cpp file:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
struct Films
{
    std::string titel;
    unsigned int year;
    int genre;
};


void main(void)
{
    Films film, film1, film2;
    film.titel = "Stargate";
    film.year = 2005;
    film.genre = 1;

    film1.titel = "V";
    film1.year = 2009;
    film1.genre = 1;

    film2.titel = "Avatar";
    film2.year = 2009;
    film2.genre = 2;

    Node<Films> films;
    films.addEntry(film);
    films.addEntry(film1);
    films.addEntry(film2);

    Iterator<Films> itr;

    for (itr = films.start(); itr != films.postpLast(); itr++)
    {
        std::cout << "Film: " << itr.getData().titel.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    _getch();
}
```

(The data is just dummy data for visualizing purposes)

I could just add a method to handle the incrementing/decrementing , but overloading the incrementing operator looks way cleaner for me (and more logical)

I hope my question is clear enough

Comment: `operator++()` defines **pre-increment**. Post increment is a separate function `operator++(int)`. You might also want to think about having them return the appropriate things, so their use is intuitive.

Comment: Wow, thanks @StoryTeller, solved it.

Comment: In the standard document, the signature is: `object& operator++()` and  `object operator++(int)`